# How do I configure Morphia/MongoDB datasource in PlayFramework 2.5 (JAVA)

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I am trying to learn the Play Framework 2.5 (JAVA) with the underlying database being MongoDB.

I am using Morphia for entity mapping.

Currently I have the mongoDB datasource configured in my java code as shown here:-

```
private static final String DATABASE = "Database";

private static final MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
private static final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);

private static final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
private static final Datastore datastore;

private static final DemeanorDAO demeanorDAO;

static {
    morphia.mapPackage("models.entity");

    datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, DATABASE);
    datastore.ensureIndexes();
}
```

How do I configure the mongoDB datasource within the `conf/application.conf`

Do I use the `PlayMorphia` module?

I have found these configuration properties:-

```
# configure mongodb host and port. Default value: 127.0.0.1:27017
morphia.db.seeds=127.0.0.1:27017
#
# configure mongodb authentication
# - username. Default value: empty
morphia.db.username=user
# - password. Default value: empty
morphia.db.password=pass
#
# configure database name. Default value: test
morphia.db.name=test
```

How does my Java code use these properties?

In which `conf/application.conf` section do I place these properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several questions in you question.

> Do I use the PlayMorphia module?

No you don't have to if you don't need specific features it provides.

> How does my Java code use these properties?

You need to inject the `Configuration` ([source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/Configuration.java)) class in the component where you want to use the configuration values.

For the connection to the database for example :

```
new MongoClientURI("mongodb://" + configuration.getString("morphia.db.seeds"));
```

I let you check the `Configuration` class to see what methods are available.

> In which conf/application.conf section do I place these properties?

There is no order in this file. A good practice is to order you properties by domain and alphabetically.

Disclaimer : you should review the way you declare the connection to the database. Don't start it in a static way, declare the connection when your [application starts](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaGlobal#Intercepting-application-start-up-and-shutdown).

Comment: c4k, thanks for answering all my questions. Dont know how I missed Play Framework Configuration class.

Comment: just as a note, GlobalSettings is deprecated and Play Framework encourages to don't use it.